# jQuery nav menu toggle without script

Tags: jquery, html, css

using this method to create nav nenu when screen is mobile but problem is it uses script

how can i do without script

i see many template using only html but i tried to do with this method

```
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </a>
```

but this doesn't works

how can do this without using any script

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <meta name="keywords" content="Graphic Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
              Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- header -->
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="header">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header-right">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"></a></li>
                            <li>
                                <div class="search2">
                                    <form>
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." >
                                        <input type="submit" value="&#xe006;" style="font-family:Flaticon">                                    </form>
                                </div></li>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                </div>
                <div class="head-nav">
                    <span class="menu"></span>
                    <ul class="cl-effect-15">
                        <li><a href="index.php" data-hover="HOME">HOME</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="404.html" data-hover="ARCHIVES">ARCHIVES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.php" data-hover="CONTACT">CONTACT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="terms and condition.php" data-hover="TERMS AND CONDITION">TERMS AND CONDITION</a></li>
                        <li><a href="privacy policy.php" data-hover="PRIVACY POLICY">PRIVACY POLICY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="login.php" data-hover="Login">Login</a></li>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <script>
            $("span.menu").click(function () {
                $(".head-nav ul").slideToggle(300, function () {
                    // Animation complete.
                });
            });
        </script>
        <!-- header -->
```

Comment: Do you mean you wish to only have the nav menu appear on mobile sizes?

Comment: it appears and works how can i do without using script

Comment: If you mean how can you "toggle" the menu on clicking, you won't be able to do this in pure CSS, you would be able to get the menu to show on a hover, but not on a button click. As answer below says you can probably do away with the JQuery aspect, but will still need Javascript.

Comment: @Callum.:  "you won't be able to do this in pure CSS, you would be able to get the menu to show on a hover, but not on a button click" Really ? https://jsfiddle.net/asxbet8f/

Comment: @EdenSource Bad wording on my part, yes that's on a button click but OP wants toggle behavior ^^

Comment: Sure, this is just an exemple that shows click event is kind of possible with only CSS. And an exemple that can help finding a solution for the OP ;)

Answer (score 0):

To have any action on your page you will likely need at least javascript (but maybe not full jquery with slide toggle).
In plain javascript, some examples:

https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Toggle-Function-Click-Drop-Down-Menus-Tutorial

Or style and code it yourself:
    $menulink.click(function() {
      $menulink.toggleClass('active');
      $menu.toggleClass('active');
      return false;
    });});

Only alternative I can think of would be with frames and hardcoding expanded/coded menus as links.

Answer (score 0):

You can create responsive mobile view menu only by using CSS. It works through determining the mobile screen size with media query `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` and creating specific CSS for it. Here is the [tutorial](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-responsive-navigation-menu) and the [demo](http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/responsive-menu/) (try re-sizing the browser to see mobile menu effect).

Comment: I think OP wants to know how to recreate his toggle behaviour without script, not just getting the menu to show on mobile sizes (what I first thought they meant too ^^)